# rsync --remove-source-files and symbolic links

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, symbolic-link, rsync

My source folder contains *only* symbolic links to different directories:

> symlink1 -> /path/to/dir1
>
> symlink2 -> /path/to/dir2

I want rsync to delete synch'd links from the source on success. I tried adding --copy-links to follow symblinks and --remove-source-files to remove them.

```
rsync -vrhuz --copy-links --remove-source-files --progress -e ssh username@remotehost:/path/containing/links /local/path
```

Unfortunately this will **delete** the *files linked by the symbolic links* instead of the **symbolic links** themself, which is I want to achieve.

Any suggestions, maybe using other techniques if rsync alone is not enough?

Answer (score -1):

You could use `--links` instead of `--copy-links`, it will remove symlinks (not referenced links), but it will sync symlinks, not referenced directories.